# Descargar table en formato Excel

Tags: javascript, vue.js, excel

Tengo una tabla con un formato muy peculiar en mi componente y me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de descargar exactamente ese mismo formato de tabla en Excel.

Graficamente se ve asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código de mi componente:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="list-content-config active">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body" v-if="show">
                            <div class="row mb-2">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div id="tickets-table_length" class="dataTables_length">
                                        <label class="d-inline-flex align-items-center">
                                            Mostrar&nbsp;
                                            <b-form-select v-model="perPage" size="sm" :options="pageOptions">
                                            </b-form-select>&nbsp;Registros
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
                                    <button class="btn btn-success text-right"> Descargar Excel</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="app-container-report-history-worked-hours">

                                <b-table table-class="table table-report-hwh table-centered w-100"
                                :bordered="bordered"
                                :small="small"
                                :hover="hover"
                                thead-tr-class="bg-light th-row-dates"
                                :items="driverListing" :fields="fields_dynamic"
                                >
                                    <template #thead-top>
                                        <b-tr>
                                            <b-th  v-for="iColTH in fieldsColSpan" :key="iColTH.label" :colspan="iColTH.numColSpan"><span>{{ iColTH.label}}</span></b-th>
                                        </b-tr>
                                    </template>
                                    <template v-slot:cell(_id_reg)="data">{{ data.item.id }}</template>
                                    <template v-slot:cell(driver_name)="data">{{ data.item.first_name+''+data.item.last_name }}</template>

                                    <template v-for="ifield in fields_dates" v-slot:[toCellName(ifield.key)]="data" >
                                        <slot v-bind="data" :name="ifield.key" v-bind:class="'description'"/>
                                        <div v-bind:key="ifield.key" :class="{'table-cell-is-week': ifield.isCellWeek == 1}">
                                            {{ onGetDataReport(data.item.id,ifield.key,ifield.isCellWeek,ifield) }}</div>
                                    </template>
                                </b-table>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <b-overlay :show="loading" rounded="sm" spinner-variant="primary">
                            <div class="card-body" v-if="!show">
                                <h3 class="text-center text-dark"> No hay datos para mostrar</h3>
                            </div>
                        </b-overlay>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

y esta es la función que genera el formato de la tabla:

```
addDynamicFields(){

            let buildFieldsColumns = [],
                dateNow = this.$moment(this.dateFrom),
                buildDateFields = [],
                prevMonth=0,
                cellWeekNum=1;

            let colHeadMonths = [];
            colHeadMonths.push({label:'',numColSpan:2});
            let col_fields_week={week_1:'00:00:00'},days_week=[];
            let dateDiff = this.$moment(this.dateTo).diff(this.$moment(this.dateFrom), "days"),colSpanCounter=1;

            buildFieldsColumns.push({label: `ID`,key: '_id_reg',sortable: false,})
            buildFieldsColumns.push({label: `Conductor`,key: 'driver_name',sortable: false,})

            for (let index = 0; index < dateDiff+1; index++) {
                if(prevMonth == 0){
                    colHeadMonths.push({label:dateNow.format('MMMM'),numColSpan:1}); colSpanCounter=1;
                }
                if(prevMonth !=0 && prevMonth != dateNow.format('M')){
                    colHeadMonths[colHeadMonths.length-1].numColSpan=colSpanCounter;
                    colHeadMonths.push({label:dateNow.format('MMMM'),numColSpan:1}); colSpanCounter=1;
                }

                days_week.push( `day_${dateNow.format('D_M')}`);
                buildDateFields.push({label: `${dateNow.format('DD.MM')}`,key: `day_${dateNow.format('D_M')}`,sortable: false,isCellWeek:0,week_num: `week_${cellWeekNum}`});
                buildFieldsColumns.push({label: `${dateNow.format('ddd, MMM D, YYYY')}`,key: `day_${dateNow.format('D_M')}`,sortable: false,isCellWeek:0});
                if(dateNow.format('d') == 0){

                    col_fields_week[`week_${cellWeekNum}`]='00:00:00';
                    buildDateFields.push({label: `Semana ${cellWeekNum}`,key: `week_${cellWeekNum}`,sortable: false,isCellWeek:1,value:'00:00:00',days_ofWeek:days_week});
                    buildFieldsColumns.push({label: `Semana ${cellWeekNum}`,key: `week_${cellWeekNum}`,sortable: false,isCellWeek:1,value:'00:00:00'});
                    cellWeekNum++; colSpanCounter++; days_week=[];
                }
                if(prevMonth !=0){ colSpanCounter++;}
                prevMonth = dateNow.format('M');
                dateNow=dateNow.add(1, 'days');
            }

            colHeadMonths[colHeadMonths.length-1].numColSpan=colSpanCounter;

            this.fieldsColSpan=colHeadMonths;
            this.fields_dates=buildDateFields;
            this.fields_weeks=col_fields_week;
            this.fields_dynamic=buildFieldsColumns;
        },
```